# Custom groupby query in Pandas, Python in which the constrains depend on multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 fields Phone number and Email. I want to group rows which are from the same person, that is, either the Phone number or Email must be the same.

Can I use groupby for this? I have already made a looping algorithm which uses dictionary etc.

Example:

```
index  phone  email
0      123    e@b.com
1      123    b@c.com
2      456    c@d.com
3      333    b@c.com
4      443    c@d.coom
```

I need pandas to group indices 0,1,3 together and the rest together

Comment: Please provide some sample data along with an example showing the expected output.

Comment: please provide some sample and the corresponding desired output that we understand your intentions and help you out

Comment: No, Pandas groupby is not the right tool. You need to represent your data as a graph and find [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)).

Comment: I have edited to give an example.

If I can't use pandas for this, should I just loop through numpy arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load the data into a graph. For example, using [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/),

```
G = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df, 'email', 'phone', 'index')
```

creates a graph with an edge between each `email` and `phone` listed in the DataFrame, and with the associated index as an attribute of the edge.

Then individuals can be identified as the [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)) of the graph:

```
components = nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G)
```

You can then find the index values associated with the edges of each component. 
The indexes can then be used to slice the original DataFrame, thus showing you all the rows associated with a single individual:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
df = pd.DataFrame({'email': ['e@b.com', 'b@c.com', 'c@d.com', 'b@c.com', 'c@d.com'], 
                   'phone': [123, 123, 456, 333, 443], 'index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]})

G = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df, 'email', 'phone', 'index')

components = nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G)
for cc in components:
    idx = [dct['index'] for node1, node2, dct in cc.edges(data=True)]
    group = df.iloc[idx]
    print(group)
    print('-'*80)
```

yields

```
     email  index  phone
2  c@d.com      2    456
4  c@d.com      4    443
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     email  index  phone
0  e@b.com      0    123
1  b@c.com      1    123
3  b@c.com      3    333
```

Comment: Thanks. It didn't strike me to use components. Also I realised that I can convert df to a numpy matrix and loop over rows instead of looping over df rows.